# Rename multiple files as "Modified Date/Time" using cmd or Powershell

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, rename

I have hundreds of JPG files in a folder. I want to rename each file so that the file name is replaced with "Modified Date/Time" of that file, namely `DD.MM.RRRR.HH.MM.jpg`. For example,

```
Before    After  

001.jpg   11.01.2011.16.58.jpg  
002.jpg   12.01.2011.09.32.jpg  
003.jpg   14.01.2011.12.41.jpg  
...       ...
```

Since colon (:) cannot be used in file names, the colon between HH and MM must be replaced with a period.

I don't want to use a 3rd party tool. Can you provide me with the code to achieve this in Powershell or command line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this in Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | Rename-Item -newname {$_.LastWriteTime.toString("dd.MM.yyyy.HH.mm") + ".jpg"}
```

Comment: Alternatively, for ordering all files in chronological order: `Get-ChildItem *.* | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('{0}{1}' -f $_.LastWriteTime.toString("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss"), $_.Extension)}`. I am using this to create GIF from multiple PNGs.

Comment: What happens if two JPG have the same modified date + hours + minutes + seconds all the same?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you guys don't mind my feedback here.

'Rename-Item' gave me this error:
*Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.*

So I've added to Siim K's solution as follows and ran this within 'Windows Powershell ISE':

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg |ForEach-Object {
    $NewName = $_.LastWriteTime.toString("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss.ss")+($script:i++) + ".jpg"
    $Destination = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.FullName -ChildPath $NewName
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination -Force
}
```

I found the 'yyyy.MM.dd.mm.ss.ss' order listed my images better and I recognized than none of my image count was reduced (accidentally purged) within the folder
as well.  I hope this is helpful to other 'superusers' (beginner or experienced).

Answer (score -1):

These responses are all well and good, but there is a 3rd party program called Advanced Renamer that will do all this in any format you want. New Name options. New Case options. Remove pattern options. Replace Options. Renumber options.  It's extremely flexible.  It even has undo option.  You drag the files you want to rename on the right side of the window and then start selecting the options you want. As you select them you see what the changes will look like before you start the batch process.

The free version is not limited.  If you like the software you can buy a license.  Why screw around with command line stuff which you will frequently mistype when you can see the proposed changes before you actually implement them?

If you want something a little more light weight you can use UltraRenamer.  It doesn't have unlimited options but it is still very useful and shows you the changes before you execute the renaming process.

Comment: the OP already said they aren't interested in 3rd party solutions. And powershell also gives you previews of the new names if you want. Why install an app just for this when powershell is already extremely powerful?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).